# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type Series)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I want to extract signals from time series data for machine learning using tensorflow. I got this error when I try to run the program.

> /Users/renzha/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.1/scratches/pywavelet.py:38: DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
> Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
> X = np.asarray(X).astype(np.float)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 129, in wrapper
> raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/renzha/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.1/scratches/pywavelet.py", line 38, in 
> X = np.asarray(X).astype(np.float)
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

However, if I use `X = np.array(X)`, then the error will be

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type Series).

I have tried `tf.convert_to_tensor(X)`, but it will return the same error.

The code is here:

````
HBT_data = []
for i in range (0,10):
    files = glob.glob('/Users/renzha/Documents/work/preparing papers/non-contact HCI/s letter' + str(i) +'/*')

    for file in files:
        names = ['time', 'signal']
        data = pd.read_csv (file, names=names)
        data = data.drop (data.index [0])
        data = data.dropna (axis=0, how='any')
        x = data.iloc[:,1]
        filename = os.path.basename (file)
        label = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        labeledArray = [label, x]
        HBT_data.append(labeledArray)

HBT_data = pd.DataFrame(HBT_data, dtype=object)
y = HBT_data.iloc[:, 0]
y = np.asarray(y)
X = HBT_data.iloc[:, 1:]
X = np.asarray(X).astype(np.float) # tried but did not work
X = tf.convert_to_tensor (X) # tried but did not work

X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=8)

X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
X_test = X_validation.reshape((X_validation.shape[0], X_validation.shape[1], 1))
num_classes = len(np.unique(Y_train))

idx = np.random.permutation(len(X_train))
x_train = X_train[idx]
y_train = X_train[idx]

Y_train[Y_train == -1] = 0
Y_validation[Y_validation == -1] = 0


def make_model(input_shape):
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(input_shape)

    conv1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same")(input_layer)
    conv1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    conv1 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv1)

    conv2 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same")(conv1)
    conv2 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    conv2 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv2)

    conv3 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same")(conv2)
    conv3 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    conv3 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv3)

    gap = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(conv3)

    output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(gap)

    return keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)


model = make_model(input_shape=X_train.shape[1:])
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)

epochs = 500
batch_size = 32

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        "best_model.h5", save_best_only=True, monitor="val_loss"
    ),
    keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
        monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=20, min_lr=0.0001
    ),
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=50, verbose=1),
]
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"],
)
history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    Y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    validation_split=0.2,
    verbose=1,
)

model = keras.models.load_model("best_model.h5")

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_validation, Y_validation)

print("Test accuracy", test_acc)
print("Test loss", test_loss)```
````

Comment: did you try `X = np.asarray(X).astype(float) `  ?

Comment: You may have null values such as NaN or None in your data. Try removing them by methods like `pd.fillna()`.

Comment: First of all, it is not easy to read all the code and separate a problem region. You should not post the code in raw format but better try to clean the unnecessary part and prepare your question to the public. Second, the `ValueError` you mention is strange because you try to create a Numpy array from X, but error tells about the Tensor. Error may be related to the consequent error you mention. Third, it seems that the problem is not related to the Tensorflow library bu to the Pandas. Try a Pandas method `pandas.Series.to_numpy` instead

Comment: Thank you. I found out that the error comes from the shape of my dataframe.